# Activating and using on board Bluetooth on orange pi

Tags: bluetooth, orange-pi

I am using an orange pi to connect to BLE devices, and I would like to use the on board ble interface, I am using OPI3 LTS OS: Orange Pi Focal with Linux 5.10.75-sunxi64

when I run `sudo hciconfig -a` I can see devices available:

```
hci1:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: 10:11:12:13:14:15  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 240:3
        UP RUNNING PSCAN
        RX bytes:213806 acl:0 sco:0 events:12843 errors:0
        TX bytes:689392 acl:0 sco:0 commands:12843 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xff 0x8d 0xfe 0xdb 0x3d 0x7b 0xc7
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy:
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
        Name: 'orangepi3-lts'
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous,
        HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x400
        LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x400
        Manufacturer: Spreadtrum Communications Shanghai Ltd (492)

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
        DOWN
        RX bytes:184866998 acl:8964 sco:0 events:5069260 errors:0
        TX bytes:1669130 acl:9985 sco:0 commands:96182 errors:16
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x5b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
```

The on board ble interface is hci1, so I shutdown my dongle hci0 and when I try doing a scan using bluetoothctl, I get this error `Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.NotReady`

I can use the hci0 to do scan though and connect to devices when I bring it up and running, but not on board hci1.

Comment: hciattach, hciconfig, hcitool, hcidump, rfcomm, sdptool, ciptool, and gatttool were [deprecated by the BlueZ](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617) project in 2017. If you are following a tutorial that uses them, there is a chance that it might be out of date. `bluetoothctl` doesn't know about changes you make with `hciconfig`. In `bluetoothctl` `list` the controllers; which one is marked as default? To change default controller use `seleect 10:11:12:13:14:15`

Comment: I did that and still can't see any devices on scan